# Wildfly 8.1 , - does not recognize my dependencies - but Glassfish does

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I am in the midst of porting my application from Glassfish to Wildfly 8.1.
The Application is an maven-ejb-project that depends on a maven-'java Application'-project, both are packaged in a jar-file when compiled.

This is a maven project ( mvn version is 3.0.5 ) , Java 1.7 and it is written in Netbeans 8.0.2.

I have created an EJB-module , the name of my deployable file is ServerApp-ejb.jar . This project has a @Startup-bean and does reading from a database.

The EJB-module relies on my 'Domain-service'-module which is a jar - >DomainService-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar . This project contains my 'entites'.

When I deploy my my ejb-app.jar in Glassfish :

I can see that Glassfish use the DomainService-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar that is located in my .m2-directory .

Pressing the Glassfish tab of 'General' I can see the following:

'Libraries'> /home/ingo/.m2/repository/se/server/tutorial/web/DomainService/2.0-SNAPSHOT/DomainService-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- it may seem odd that Glassfish manages its dependencies like this, but this is how glassfish does, apparantly.

I understand that class-loading is done differently in Wildfly than it is done in Glassfish.

I have seen some recommendation regarding war-files and ear-files.

My EJB has the following lines in my  pom.xml

se.nrm.mediaserver

ServerApp-ejb

1.0-SNAPSHOT

ejb

And the following dependencies :

```
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>javax</groupId>

        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>

        <version>6.0</version>

        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>

   <dependency>

        <groupId>se.server.tutorial.web</groupId>

        <artifactId>DomainService</artifactId>

        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <type>jar</type>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>junit</groupId>

        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

        <version>${junit.version}</version>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>log4j</groupId>

        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

        <version>${log4j.version}</version>

        <type>jar</type>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The only file in the above dependency list that is not found is my own.

Could anyone advice me on the right thing to do, I would rather not change my packaging style ejb.

regards, ingo

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly uses classloading mechanism based on the concept of modules. They modules must be defined and a dependency declared either in the standalone.xml or within a specific jboss-deployment-structure.xml within your META-INF/WEB-INF folder, and {user.home}/.m2/ is not one of the paths of the jboss modules.

That said, deploying your interface declarations as module in wildfly doesnt seems like a logical idea.

Create a application-deployment.ear, and add the applcation-ejb.jar as a dependency to it and this will be portable across application servers,glassfish, weblogic, wildfly.